# How to rotate a 2D line in PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, coordinate-transformation, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I've written a code to draw a line. Here is the function:

```
def drawLines():
    r,g,b = 255,30,20
    #drawing visible axis
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3ub(r,g,b)
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    #glRotate(10,500,-500,0)
    glVertex2f(0,500)
    glVertex2f(0,-500)

    glEnd()
    glFlush()
```

Now I'm trying to rotate the line. I'm trying to follow [this](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glRotate.html) documentation but can't understand. According to the documentation the rotating function is defined as follows:

```
def glRotate( angle , x , y , z ):
```

I've no z-axis. So I'm keeping `z=0`. What i'm I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences nad the fixed function pipeline matrix stack, is deprecated since decades.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering:

---

The `x`, `y` and `z` parameter which are passed to [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) are the axis of rotation. Since geometry is drawn in the xy-plane, the axis of rotation has to be the z-axis (0,0,1):

```py
glRotatef(10, 0, 0, 1)
```

To rotate around a pivot you have to define a model matrix, which displaces by the inverted pivot, then rotates and final transforms back by to the pivot ([`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml)):

```py
glTranslatef(pivot_x, pivot_y, 0)
glRotatef(10, 0, 0, 1)
glTranslatef(-pivot_x, -pivot_y, 0)
```

Further note that operations like `glRotate` are not allowed within a [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence. In [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence only operations are allowed which set the vertex attributes like [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) or [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml). You have to set the matrix before `glBegin`:

e.g.

```py
def drawLines():
    pivot_x, pivot_y = 0, 250
    r,g,b = 255,30,20

    glTranslatef(pivot_x, pivot_y, 0)
    glRotatef(2, 0, 0, 1)
    glTranslatef(-pivot_x, -pivot_y, 0)

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3ub(r,g,b)

    #drawing visible axis
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glVertex2f(0,500)
    glVertex2f(0,-500)
    glEnd()

    glFlush()
```

---

If you want to rotate the line only, without affecting other objects, then you have save and restore the matirx stack by [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml):

```
angle = 0

def drawLines():
    global angle 
    pivot_x, pivot_y = 0, 250
    r,g,b = 255,30,20

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    glPushMatrix()

    glTranslatef(pivot_x, pivot_y, 0)
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1)
    angle += 2
    glTranslatef(-pivot_x, -pivot_y, 0)

    glColor3ub(r,g,b)

    #drawing visible axis
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glVertex2f(0,500)
    glVertex2f(0,-500)
    glEnd()

    glPopMatrix()

    glFlush()
```

Comment: wow! it worked! Thank You. Is there any good material/resource to learn PyOpenGL? And what is the difference between glRotate() and glRotatef() ?

Comment: `glRotatef` is for single precision floating points (`float`) like `glVertex2f`. There are a lot of tutorials all over the web. Google found [Python & OpenGL for Scientific Visualization](http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/python-opengl/) , which looks good.

Comment: Another problem! I had another function in the program to draw another line. This line has rotated too. Any solution?

Comment: @exiled See the extension to the answer